# i want to display this listview on scrolling

Tags: android

I'm completely stumped on this one. I have three different lists that need to be displayed on the screen.
I've tried using a ScrollView with a LinearLayout child, and putting my ListViews in the LinearView, but all of the ListViews lock to a fixed height with scroll bars. Using other kinds of Layouts means no scrolling.

Comment: ListViews knows how to scroll. You don't have to put it in Scrollview. Draw a picture and tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: Not only do you not have to put it in a `ScrollView`, but it won't work in a `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the listviews in your linearlayout are dependant on how you weight them.

Do you have some sample code?

Try this layout (not tested)

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="fill_parent"
android:height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list1"
android:width="fill_parent"
android:height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list2"
android:width="fill_parent"
android:height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list3"
android:width="fill_parent"
android:height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
>

</LinearLayout>
```